# how can we be sure that there are any limit ordinals?

Tags: ordinals

The first limit-ordinal $\omega $ is the least-upper bound of the finite ordinals. There is no greatest finite-ordinal. So $\omega $ is not among the finite ordinals. But why then suppose that the finite ordinals have a least-upper bound at all?

Suppose it is because the finite ordinals are collected as a set. Then this set itself witnesses the existence of $\omega$. Doesn't this beg the question? In virtue of what are we entitled to assume that the finite ordinals are collectable?

Comment: That's why it's an **axiom**, it's part of our assumptions.

Comment: It also depends on your axioms if the collection of finite ordinals is an honest set, or a proper class in your theory.

Comment: Elaborating on Asaf's comment, the relevant axiom is the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity). (At least, this is assuming that we're working in [the usual set theory framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory); as James said above, different systems behave differently, and there are indeed alternate set theories where there is no set of all finite ordinals.)

Comment: thank you all! that is really helpful.